# How can I set IP on Debian for multiple interface?

Tags: debian, network-interface

I want to put in place a network balancing cluster for a web server on Debian. So I must use 2 network adapters for this service. The first one will be for the local network and the second one will be for a separate cluster network.

network 1: 172.16.0.0 
network 2: 192.168.17.0

I modified this file `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
#interface 1
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static 
address 172.16.17.229
netmask 255.255.0.0
broadcast 172.16.255.255
gateway 172.16.0.1
dns-* options are implemented by resolconf package, if installed
dns-server 172.16.17.20

#interface 2
allow-hotplug enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static 
address 192.168.17.229
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.17.255
```

After configuring the second interface, I am not able to ping www.google.com. I want to know where the problem comes from.

*I have restarted the computer and still not able to.

Comment: What happens when you try to `ping`?  Add the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf` to your question.

Comment: Your line that has `dns-* options ... ` should be commented out

Comment: when i ping www.google.com, it says name or service unknown

Comment: @garethTheRed, and /etc/resol.conf has this line: nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: Did the system resolve names before you added the second interface definition? If so, what did you change apart from adding that second interface? (If not, you need to fix that first.)

Comment: @roaima - meant the line that actually has `dns-* options are implemented by resolconf package, if installed`, not the `dns-server 172.16.17.20` line...  could be causing an error if it isn't really commented out in your `interfaces` file

Comment: @roaima, yes i could ping www.google.com before adding IP to my second interface. And when i added the second ip for the second interface, i couldn't ping www.google.com

Comment: Please run `ifdown enp0s8` and then report any messages from `ifup enp0s8`

Comment: @roaima i have restarted the computer! Do you think ifup & ifdown is better that restarting the computer?

Comment: If you can see the messages from `ifup` when you restart the computer, that's as good a way as any.